# How to sort a Comparator with dynamic parameters?

Tags: java, comparator

Is it possible to create a static `Comparator` (so I don't have to recreate the object on each comparison), but still pass a dynamic value for compare?

In the following example, I want to pass a `String dynaval` parameter during compare. But how?

```
private final Comparator<Person> COMPARATOR = Comparator.comparing(person -> {
     if (person.getFirstname() != null) return person.getFirstname();
     return evaluateWithDynamicProperty(person, dynaval);
}

Collections.sort(persons, COMPARATOR); //TODO how to pass dynamic String?
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make a method:

```
private final Comparator<Person> personComparator(String dynaValue) {
  return Comparator.comparing(person -> {
     if (person.getFirstname() != null) return person.getFirstname();
     return evaluateWithDynamicProperty(person, dynaval);
}
```

Invoke like:

```
Collections.sort(persons, personComparator(dynaValue));
```

Or, use a lambda:

```
String personComparatorFn(Person person, String dynaValue) {
     if (person.getFirstname() != null) return person.getFirstname();
     return evaluateWithDynamicProperty(person, dynaval);
}
```

and invoke like:

```
Collections.sort(persons, Comparator.comparing(p -> personComparatorFn(p, dynaValue));
```

Comment: Ok, but are there any drawbacks that the `Comparator.comparing()` is not set into a final field? Meaning, does java always recreate the comparator object here?

Comment: The drawback of (suspected) performance problems are vastly outweighed by actually doing what you need. If you can confirm there is a performance issue, you could cache instances; but I would try without first.